# The number of sub series in a given list of numbers

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

so I have this question.
I have to write an algorithm in the most efficient way (lowest runtime) that receives 2 numbers, N and K.
5 < N < 100000, and K > 0.
After that, it receives N positive integers (List of numbers), then it prints how many sub series (not necessarily continues) in a condition that in each sub series there are at least 2 numbers, and each number in the sub series is smaller by K of the following number in the same sub series.

For example: N=6, K=5.
And the list of numbers: 1 6 8 11 12 20.
The print is 17. (17 sub series)

(6 1),  (8 6 1),  (11 8 6 1),  (12 11 8 6 1),  (12 8 6 1),  (11 6 1),  (12 11 6 1),

(8 6),  (11 8 6),  (12 11 8 6),  (12 8 6),  (11 6),  (12 11 6),

(11 8),  (12 11 8),  (12 8),

(12 11).

(From right to left (smallest to biggest))
It will only print 17 (the number of them).
Well, i've tried to write an algorithm, but i think it's bad and i believe that there's a better way to do it, mine was O(N^3). It was messy and complicated, i believe that there's some kind of a trick that I'm missing..
Sorry for my bad english and if i didn't explain something properly.
Thank you for your help! I appreciate it! ;)

Comment: you mean the next number has to be smaller than previous with difference of at most  K ?

Comment: also the sub sequence does not have have elements in same sequence  ?

Comment: I mean, in the sub sequence for example, 1 6 8 11, "1 6". 1 is smaller than 6, by 5.. Which is K in that example, if it was "1 7" then it's wrong, since 7>1 by 6 which is bigger than K

Comment: Also the sequences have elements of any give list, but they can also be non continues in the list, for example the list: 1 6 8 11 12 20. The sub sequence "1 6 11" is counted, and also "8 12".. Even though they're not continues in the original list

Comment: What is the answer if two elements are equal? If the given array is {2, 2, 2}, is the answer 2 or 4?

Comment: I think it'd be an increasing sequence, but in this situation I'd say that the answer is 4.

Comment: Looks like an interview question (Google?). I would say the first step here is for you to figure out what the actual _specification_ here is. If someone asks you what the output for some specific input would be, and the best you can say is "I think it'd be..." and/or "I'd say that...", then you don't have a good specification. There should be no doubt in your mind as to what would happen. If you don't even know for sure, how can you expect anyone else to know and to help?

Comment: It's a training question in programming, i have an exam in about a week. It's really complicated and takes time to solve, I've found some tricks that could be useful in order to solve it, ill add them later because I'm not on my computer at the moment. Just consider it as an increasing sequence, it doesn't state that in the question that i received, but i believe it should be done this way. Anyways, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the problem statement correctly, but I'll try to give some idea.

First, sort the sequence in the increasing order, for instance. That should take you O(n log n).

Suppose your sorted array is A. Than, for each element, count how many valid sequences exist such that they are ending in the given element. Let's denote this number as f(l) where l is an index of element in A. Suppose you solved this for all elements with index less then i; than f(i) is the sum of all f(j) such that j < i and A[i]-A[j] <= K.

In result you should get something like O(n^2) solution.